# Find and replace text with special characters

Tags: c#, string, replace, visual-studio-2015

I have a bunch of scripts with specific lines I need to change into others.

For example my main looks like this:

```
string Path = @"C:\foo\bar\bin\";
string Conf = "foo.bar.conf.bat";
string OldValue = "rem set \"PARAM =% PARAM % -Foo:BAR = foo,bar = 123,fff = bbb,aaa\"";
string NewValue = "set \"PARAM =% PARAM % -Foo:BAR = foo,bar = 123,fff = bbb,aaa\"";
Console.WriteLine(FART(Path + Conf, OldValue, NewValue));

private static string FART(string PathToFile, string OldValue, string NewValue)
{
    string file = File.ReadAllText(PathToFile);
    OldValue = OldValue.Replace(@"\", "");
    NewValue = NewValue.Replace(@"\", "");
    file = file.Replace(OldValue, NewValue);
    File.WriteAllText(PathToFile, file);

    string output = PathToFile + " " + OldValue + " " + NewValue;

    return output;
}
```

The string I need to uncomment is unique in this file. My problem is that the file is changed (I can see the modified date changing) but the content is the same.

Concerning similar questions this approach should work as far as I can see..

Comment: What is the `output` you're getting?

Comment: What's the content in the file? Your code replaces a line that contains `rem set "PARAM =% PARAM % -Foo:BAR = foo,bar = 123,fff = bbb,aaa"`

Comment: Why are you doing `Replace(@"\", "")`?  There are no actual backslashes in your strings, just backslashes used as escape characters for the double quotes.

Comment: @MatiasCicero No, that will remove backslashes, but since there are none, it's a no-op.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the foo.bar.conf.bat file?  Is it possible that you have a case sensitivity issue like REM instead of rem.

Comment: @juharr there is no case sensitive issue or similar because I copy & pasted ´OldValue´ and in ´NewValue´ I just removed the first 3 letters. In addition I escape the inner 2 double quotes. The relevant content of *.bat is shown in the code and the rest should not matter when I took a look at the debugger.

Comment: @Shaharyar the ´output´ is not really relevant here. It will just display a concatenated string with path to my file, old and new value. You can see them in my "main" method the output.

Answer (score 0):

The file located at `PathToFile` does not have any occurances of `OldValue`.

Your logic for formatting `OldValue` and `NewValue` is likely wrong.

From this line:

```
OldValue = OldValue.Replace(@"\", "");
```

I can see that you'd like to remove backslashes from `OldValue`, however the way you've defined `OldValue`:

```
string OldValue = "rem set \"PARAM =% PARAM % -Foo:BAR = foo,bar = 123,fff = bbb,aaa\"";
```

It doesn't have any backslashes to begin with.

Note that when you use `\"` in a string in C#, it really only inserts a `"`. (Unless of course you prefix your string with the `@`).

If you delete these two lines, it should work:

```
OldValue = OldValue.Replace(@"\", "");
NewValue = NewValue.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Comment: Removing those lines will not change anything or "make it work".  But they should be removed because they don't do anything useful.  As you state in your first sentence the real problem is that the `OldValue` is not in the file.

Comment: @vivekmaharajh My file most certainly does have a occurence of ´OldValue´ as I just copied and pasted that line into my editor.

Comment: Aight.  In that case, please share the input file with us so we can debug further